# kohana orm join duplicate objects result

Tags: orm, kohana-3

I'm trying to query the country table with the below query to print all countries with the corresponding cities. Now i'm getting a duplicated country object for each city instead of have one country object for all cities.

```
$all = ORM::factory('country')->select('cities.*')->join('cities','LEFT')->on('country.id', '=', 'country_id' )->find-all();

foreach ($all as $country) {
    echo $caountry->name;
    foreach($country->cities as $city ){
        echo $city->name;
    }
}
```

Appreciate your help,
AA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL and only need the name of the city, you can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function and then convert it to array using PHP's explode.

```
    $all = ORM::factory('country')
    ->select('country.name',DB::epxr('GROUP_CONCAT(cities.name) AS cities'))
    ->join('cities','LEFT')
    ->on('country.id', '=', 'country_id' )
    ->group_by("country.id")
    ->find-all();

foreach ($all as $country) {
    echo $country->name;
    foreach(explode(",",$country->cities) as $city ){
        echo $city;
    }
}
```